# Neo4jClient and async transactions

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm implementing Neo4jClient to use async transactions and the [wiki](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/Transactions) says :

> To use the TransactionScope with async, assuming you're compiling against .NET >4.5.1 or higher, you construct the TransactionScope using the >TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption parameter:
>
> ```
> using (var scope = new > TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
> {
>     await client.Cypher.Create("(n:Tx {Name:'Test'})").ExecuteWithoutResultsAsync();
>     scope.Complete();
> }
> ```

But I can't find a reference to `TransactionScope`. I currently have:

```
using (ITransaction transaction = _client.BeginTransaction(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
{
    _client.Create(.....);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Is this the correct way to handle async transactions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TransactionScope` is `System.Transactions.TransactionScope`

Comment: Great, thanks. Didn't realise it was part of the .Net library, I thought it was part of Neo4jClient.